# Using ADAL with Logstash Custom Plugin const errors

Tags: ruby, logstash, adal

I'm working to create a Logstash Input plugin to utilize ADAL for integration with the Office 365 Management Activity API's. I've written the individual components to get a token, use that token to subscribe, and to pull activity log data.

Now I'm working to integrate into the Logstash framework, and running into issues where Logstash is complaining that it's doesn't know what ADAL is, even though I have it required.

All the same code works independently outside of Logstash, just not within the plugin class.

This is my first foray into Ruby, so I'm pretty stumped. Any help?

Error message from Logstash:

```
[2018-09-16T00:51:32,816][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-09-16T00:51:33,921][INFO ][logstash.inputs.office365managementapi] Starting Office 365 Management API input...
[2018-09-16T00:51:34,246][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"<LogStash::Inputs::Office365ManagementApi client_id=>\"redacted\", tenant_id=>\"redacted\", tenant_domain=>\"redacted\", private_key=>\"/tmp/o365.pfx\", subscriptions=>[\"Audit.AzureActiveDirectory\", \"Audit.Exchange\", \"Audit.SharePoint\", \"Audit.General\", \"DLP.All\"], id=>\"fb61b83b76494f098a0a7e24391779ee1212f0d9adf8ef8dedae4424e8dedb57\", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>\"plain_c7c9d514-5d23-459d-98ea-87d250e7a00c\", enable_metric=>true, charset=>\"UTF-8\">, resource=>\"https://manage.office.com\">", :error=>"uninitialized constant LogStash::Inputs::Office365ManagementApi::ADAL::Logging\nDid you mean?  LogStash::Logging", :thread=>"#<Thread:0xca2e135 run>"}
[2018-09-16T00:51:34,367][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<NameError: uninitialized constant LogStash::Inputs::Office365ManagementApi::ADAL::Logging
Did you mean?  LogStash::Logging>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3343:in `const_missing'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/vendor/local_gems/82bdbf8d/logstash-input-office365_management_api-1.0.0/lib/logstash/inputs/office365_management_api.rb:70:in `register'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `register_plugin'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:353:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:353:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:500:in `start_inputs'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:394:in `start_workers'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290:in `run'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:250:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0xca2e135 run>"}
[2018-09-16T00:51:34,418][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

Code is below:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "logstash/inputs/base"
require "logstash/namespace"
require "stud/interval"
require "socket" # for Socket.gethostname
require "json"
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

# Using this input you can receive activities from the Office 365 Management API
# ==== Security
# This plugin utilizes certificate authentication with the Office 365 Management API
# to generate an access token, which is then used for all subsequent API activities.
# If the token expires, the plugin will request a new token automatically.
# All communication for this plugin is encrypted by SSL/TLS communication.

class LogStash::Inputs::Office365ManagementApi < LogStash::Inputs::Base
  config_name "office365_management_api"

  # Codec used to decode the incoming data.
  # This codec will be used as a fall-back if the content-type
  # is not found in the "additional_codecs" hash
  default :codec, "plain"

  # Fix for broken ruby ADAL
  module ADAL
   class TokenRequest
    module GrantType
     JWT_BEARER = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer'
    end
   end
  end

  # Client ID generated through your custom application in Azure AD
  # https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps
  config :client_id, :validate => :string, :required => true

  # Tenant ID/Directory ID of your Office 365 tenant
  # https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties
  config :tenant_id, :validate => :string, :required => true

  # Your Office 365 tenant domain, ie. yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com
  config :tenant_domain, :validate => :string, :required => true

  # Resource you are requesting access to. This defaults to https://manage.office.com and shouldn't change unless necessary.
  config :resource, :validate => :string, :default => 'https://manage.office.com'

  # PFX Private key for your Application Certificate you created
  config :private_key, :validate => :path

  # Private key password if one was used
  config :private_key_password, :validate => :string, :default => nil

  # Activity subscriptions you want to monitor
  # These can be one or many of:
  # Audit.AzureActiveDirectory
  # Audit.Exchange
  # Audit.Sharepoint
  # Audit.General
  # DLP.All
  config :subscriptions, :validate => :array, :default => ["Audit.AzureActiveDirectory", "Audit.Exchange", "Audit.SharePoint", "Audit.General", "DLP.All"]

  public
  def register
    require "adal"
    @logger.info("Starting Office 365 Management API input...")
    @host = Socket.gethostname

    # ADAL supports four logging options: VERBOSE, INFO, WARN and ERROR.
    ADAL::Logging.log_level = ADAL::Logger::VERBOSE

  end # def register

  def get_token
    @logger.info("Generating access token...")
    if @private_key_password.nil?
        pfx = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(@private_key))
    else
        pfx = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(@private_key), @private_key_password)
    end

    authority = ADAL::Authority.new("login.microsoftonline.com", @tenant_domain)
    client_cred = ADAL::ClientAssertionCertificate.new(authority, @client_id, pfx)
    result = ADAL::AuthenticationContext
          .new("login.microsoftonline.com", @tenant_domain)
          .acquire_token_for_client(@resource, client_cred)

    case result
     when ADAL::SuccessResponse
       puts 'Successfully authenticated with client credentials. Received access ' "token: #{result.access_token}."
       # Create class variable for reuse of Access Token
       @access_token = result.access_token
       @http_headers = {
        'Authorization' => "Bearer #{@access_token}",
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       }

     when ADAL::FailureResponse
       puts 'Failed to authenticate with client credentials. Received error: ' "#{result.error} and error description: #{result.error_description}."
       exit 1
    end
  end #def get_token

  def check_subscription
    @logger.info("Checking for proper subscriptions...")
    @subscriptions.each do |sub|
      sub_uri = URI("https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/#{@tenant_id}/activity/feed/subscriptions/start?contentType=#{sub}")
      sub_http = Net::HTTP.new(sub_uri.host, sub_uri.port)
      sub_http.use_ssl = true
      sub_resp = http.post(sub_uri.request_uri, data = "", @http_headers)

      case sub_resp
       when Net::HTTPSuccess
         puts "Created subscription to #{sub} in tenant #{@tenant_id}..."
       when Net::HTTPUnauthorized
         puts "Authentication Error Encountered: #{sub_resp.message}"
       when Net::HTTPServerError
         puts "Server Error Encountered: #{sub_resp.message}"
       else
         puts "Unknown Error Encountered: #{sub_resp.message}"
      end
    end
  end #def check_subscription

  def run(queue)
    # we can abort the loop if stop? becomes true
    while !stop?
      #event = LogStash::Event.new("message" => @message, "host" => @host)
      #decorate(event)
      #queue << event
      raise 'Error getting token' unless get_token().status == 0

      # because the sleep interval can be big, when shutdown happens
      # we want to be able to abort the sleep
      # Stud.stoppable_sleep will frequently evaluate the given block
      # and abort the sleep(@interval) if the return value is true
      Stud.stoppable_sleep(@interval) { stop? }
    end # loop
  end # def run

  def stop
    # nothing to do in this case so it is not necessary to define stop
    # examples of common "stop" tasks:
    #  * close sockets (unblocking blocking reads/accepts)
    #  * cleanup temporary files
    #  * terminate spawned threads
  end
end # class LogStash::Inputs::Office365ManagementApi
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug when using empty passwords with logstash.

The code responsible for this comes from the calculate_property method in HttpClient , that treats empty strings as nil:

```
  default = nil if default.is_a?(String) && default.empty? # Blanks are as good as nil
  uri_value = nil if uri_value.is_a?(String) && uri_value.empty?
```

One way to fix this is by upgrading to the latest Logstash, if you are currently using an older version.